# Diskpart detail disk with powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to display physical disk info with output file with details of Disk ID, Disk type, LUN ID and etc with each disk using power-shell script.

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what *specific* problem (in your code) do you need help with?

Answer (score -1):

```
$DRIVELIST=(GET-DISKPARTINFO | WHERE { $_.Type –eq $TYPE –and $_.DiskSize -lt $MAX -and $_.DiskSize –gt $MIN })

$DRIVELIST | FOREACH {

$Source=”C:DeploymentContent”
$Destination=$_.DriveLetter

ROBOCOPY $Source $Destination /E

}
```